# How to get the maxIntensity property on a google heatmap

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, data-visualization, heatmap

I've googled, looked through S.O., and even just ran through the javascript properties using firebug, but I just can't find a way to *get* the `maxIntensity` property in a google heatmap. I can set `maxIntensity`, when instantiating the new map.

According to the docs here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.10/reference#HeatmapLayer

there's no method for getting to the heatmap options object either, just setting as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can get it, assuming `heatmap` is the heatmap layer:

`heatmap.get('maxIntensity')`

Comment: I am using the heatmap layer, but it's only returning undefined. That seems odd, because there must be either some default value internally or it's calculated.

Comment: The default value is generated automatically so it returns undefined for some reason, I'm running into the same issue myself so I just give it a default value.

Answer (score 0):

First, would suggest taking a look at the [Google Maps Documentationj](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial). The provided solution seems correct, you can double check with the 
[heatmap](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/heatmaplayer) section.

```
let heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: locations,
    map: map,
    maxIntensity: maxI,
    radius: rad,
    opacity: opac
});
```

Comment: This answer needs some more explanation.